# Compiling with Cython on Windows: missing source filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, cl, cythonize

I'm trying to compile a hello world example with Cython on Windows 10. 
I have visual studio 2015 community. 
Python 3.5.2

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup (
   name='print hello world',
   ext_modules=cythonize("print_h_w.pyx", compiler_directives=
   {'language_level': 3}),
)
```

The file I'm trying to compile looks like this:

```
print('Hello World')
```

I build with this command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe 
/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -
IC:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\include -
IC:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\include "-IC:\Program 
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files 
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\" /Tcprint_h_w.c 
/Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\print_h_w.obj
cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I've been doing a lot of research but I've turned up a lot of nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: As a workaround, I started up a Windows 10 virtual machine, installed python 3.5.2, Cython (via pip), and the Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools. Everything worked as it should on the VM...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have import `cython` in your `print_h_w.pyx` file :

```
import cython
print("hello world")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't work, and is unnecessary according to my test on a virtual machine.